# Объясните работу функции, пожалуйста!

Tags: python, django, декоратор

Есть задача добавить возможность просмотров поста(с возможностью накрутки) в учебных целях.
В интернете нашел такой код:

models.py:

```py
class PageHit(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py:

```py
from django.db.models import F
from functools import wraps
from django.db import transaction

def counted(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            counter, created = PageHit.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
            counter.count = F('count') + 1
            counter.save()
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Этим декоратором оборачивается `view` для показа поста.

Код работает исправно, и при нажатии на ссылку для перехода на пост количество просмотров действительно увеличивается, но я не понимаю как работает эта функция. Пожалуйста, объясните.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Каждый раз, перед тем как вызывать данный `view`, обернутый этим декоратором, в `PageHit` с данным `url` инкрементируется `count`:

```
def counted(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # делаем транзакцию атомической (если что-то зафейлится, изменения ролбэкнутся)
        with transaction.atomic():

             # получаем объект PageHit с данным url (если его еще не существует, создаем)
            counter, created = PageHit.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)

            # инкрементируем его counter (counter.count += 1 тоже бы сработало)
            counter.count = F('count') + 1

            # сохраняем
            counter.save()

        # наконец вызываем сам view который декорировали
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Советую почитать, как работают декораторы. Вкратце на ваши вопросы:

1. `f` - это сама функция, которую мы оборачиваем, в данном случае наш `view` (поэтому в конце мы ее вызываем). `decorator` здесь довольно сбивающее с толку название, т.к. это не декоратор. `counted` в данном примере является декоратором, а то что здесь названо `decorator` обычно называют `wrapper`, это функция которая подменяет (оборачивает) декарируемую функцию:

   ```
   @counted
   def view(...):
       ...
   ```

   эквивалентно:

   ```
   def view(...):
       ...
   view = counted(view)
   ```

   [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) - вспомагательный метод django ORM, для более "низкоуровневой" коммуникации с ДБ через SQL. Как и писал выше, можно использовать более простой метод с `+=`.
2. [`wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) используется для того, чтобы сохранить оригинальноее имя (`view.__name__`) и оригинальную документацию (`view.__doc__`) декарируемой функции. Иначе ее имя заменится (в данном случае) на `decorator`, а документация пропадет, т.к. у `decorator` нет док-строки.
3. [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) возвращает кортеж из двух значений `(object, created)` - созданный или найденный объект и булеан был объект создан или найден уже существующий в ДБ по URL. Можно использовать `_` для неиспользованных переменных:

```
counter, _ = PageHit.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
```

но `created` более наглядно (IMHO).